# How to programmatically retrieve editing history pages from MusicBrainz using python?

Tags: python, web, musicbrainz

I'm trying to programmatically retrieve editing history pages from the MusicBrainz website. (`musicbrainzngs` is a library for the MB web service, and editing history is not accessible from the web service). For this, I need to login to the MB website using my username and password.

I've tried using the `mechanize` module, and using the login page second form (first one is the search form), I submit my username and password; from the response, it seems that I successfully login to the site; however, a further request to an editing history page raises an exception:

```
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt
```

I understand the exception and the reason for it. I take full responsibility for not abusing the site (after all, any usage will be tagged with my username), I just want to avoid manually opening a page, saving the HTML and running a script on the saved HTML. Can I overcome the 403 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to circumvent the site's `robots.txt`, you can achieve this by telling your `mechanize.Browser` to ignore the `robots.txt` file.

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
```

Additionally, you might want to alter your browser's user agent so you dont look like a robot:

```
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
```

Please be aware that when doing this, you're actually tricking the website into thinking you're a valid client.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for the warning. This does it.

Answer (score 2):

The better solution is to respect the robots.txt file and simply download the edit data itself and not screen scrape MusicBrainz. You can down load the complete edit history here:

ftp://ftp.musicbrainz.org/pub/musicbrainz/data/fullexport

Look for the file mbdump-edit.tar.bz2.

And, as the leader of the MusicBrainz team, I would like to ask you to respect robots.txt and download the edit data. Thats one of the reasons why we make the edit data downloadable.

Thanks!

Comment: The load will be about **90** requests (only the first page of some recording edits) in a **month**, checking for pointers that some PUID association or disassociation might be mistaken; recent enough data are almost a requirement for my purposes. I just want to automate what I would in any case do manually. But if you prefer I download 1.5 GiB of data every time more recent data become available, I'll do as you suggest. Thanks for the pointers.